# Combine hover and click functions (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, hover

Can hover and click functions be combined into one, so for example:

click:

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  // common operation
});
```

hover:

```
$('#target').hover(function () {
    // common operation
});
```

can they be combined into one function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use basic programming composition: create a method and pass the same function to `click` and `hover` as a callback.

```
var hoverOrClick = function () {
    // do something common
}
$('#target').click(hoverOrClick).hover(hoverOrClick);
```

---

Second way: use <strike>`bind`</strike>`on`:

```
$('#target').on('click mouseover', function () {
    // Do something for both
});
```

---

```
jQuery('#target').bind('click mouseover', function () {
    // Do something for both
});
```

Comment: The jquery "on" function is now recommend over using bind. But it works in the same way, just replace "bind" with "on".

Comment: Hint me, please, how I can define what did event (click or hover )happened?

Comment: I am getting some problem because of this. I have to call different functions on both hover and click. But when I click on an element both functions are called at a time. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @SarfrazAhmad This is because before the user is able to click, she has to hover. Maybe you don't need to do anything on click.

Comment: yeah, but how can i prevent a function to be called on hover when i clicked on an element

Comment: the second way is not working for me. mouseover instead of hover does work but it causes multiple animation.

Comment: hover will not work..better go with Vergilius's answer..tested and working

Answer (score 29):

Use *mouseover* instead hover.

```
$('#target').on('click mouseover', function () {
    // Do something for both
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#target").hover(function(){
  $(this).click();
}).click(function(){
  //common function
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.bind()` or `.live()` whichever is appropriate, but no need to name the function:

```
$('#target').bind('click hover', function () {
 // common operation
});
```

or if you were doing this on lots of element (not much sense for an IE unless the element changes):

```
$('#target').live('click hover', function () {
 // common operation
});
```

Note, this will only bind the **first** hover argument, the `mouseover` event, it won't hook anything to the `mouseleave` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hoverAndClick = function() {
    // Your actions here
} ;

$("#target").hover( hoverAndClick ).click( hoverAndClick ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('#myelement').bind('click hover', function yourCommonHandler (e) {
   // Your handler here
});
```

Comment: A heads up for any future readers not already aware 'As of jQuery 3.0, `.bind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.' http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

i think best approach is to make a **common** method and call in **hover** and **click** *events*.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#target").on({
        hover: function(){
           //do on mouse hover
        },  
        click: function(){
            //do on mouse click
        }  
    });
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.