# Hover and click functionality on same div

Tags: jquery

What is the right way to attach both hover and onclik functionality on the same div?

Here's what I tried but it didn't work (clicking does nothing):

```
$(function outlineHider(){
    $("#hotspot").hover(
        function() {
            $("#outlines").show(); //showing another div element
            function bindClick() {
                $("#hotspot").click(callAnotherFunction())};
            }, 
            function() {
                $("#outlines").hide();
            }
        );  
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432003/combine-hover-and-click-functions-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() { // document ready handler shortcut
    $("#hotspot").hover(
        function() { $("#outlines").show(); }, 
        function() { $("#outlines").hide(); }
    ).click(function() {
        callAnotherFunction()
    }); 
});
```

Or a shorter version, with thanks to @VisioN:

```
$(function() {
    $("#hotspot")
        .hover(function() { $("#outlines").toggle(); })
        .click(callAnotherFunction);    
});
```

Comment: `$("#hotspot").hover( function() { $("#outlines").toggle(); } )` should also work, but shorter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() { 
    $("#hotspot")
        .hover(
            function() { $("#outlines").show(); }, //mousein
            function() { $("#outlines").hide(); }  //mouseout
        )

        .click(function() { 
            callAnotherFunction();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, this should help you.

```
$(function outlineHider(){
    $("#hotspot").hover(
        function() {
            $("#outlines").show(); //showing another div element
    }),click(function(){
       $("#outlines").hide();
    });
});
```

> [Combine hover and click functions (jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432003/combine-hover-and-click-functions-jquery)
>
> var hoverOrClick = function () {
>       // do something common } $('#target').click(hoverOrClick).hover(hoverOrClick);
>
> Second way: use bind:
>
> $('#target').bind('click hover', function () {
>       // Do something for both });