# how to put mouseover and mouseclick on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a href tag. I need to open one popup on mouseover and need to open another page on clicking that tag.

I need something like this;

```
<a href='#'onclick='method1();' onmouseover ='method2();'>SOMETHING</a>
```

`method2()` will open a popup. `method1()` will redirect to another page.

The problem is that when i try to click, popup is opening always (method2 gets called). How to fix this?

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: It's hard to answer without code, but I think you need to check if the popup was already open, and run method1 if not.

Comment: mouseover will *always* fire before click. So you need to handle this manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432003/combine-hover-and-click-functions-jquery

Comment: Probably you need to have some button in your popup which will call your `method1()` to redirect to another page because whenever you try to click link it will open popup first and you won't be able to click your link.

Comment: On method2() am opening a popup, in which i have to show some information, but on method1() i have to open another page. The problem is that, whenever i try to click popup is opening.

Comment: `onmouseover` is always going to call when ever you are going to call `click`. you should should 'method1' on some 'element' on `pop up` to `redirect` to another page

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to detect user's intention of clicking or not the link. So, every time user enters the mouse over the link, the popup function will get executed.

You could set a timeout. If user does not click the link in that time limit, the popup will get alerted

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#link', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (!that.hasClass('clicked')) {
       alert('popup on hover!!');
    }
  }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('click', '#link', function() { 
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('clicked');
  alert('clicked!!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="">Link</a>
```

Comment: if you click on the link, your alert for hovering is triggered too

Comment: Actually its working.But one problem is there,On clicking popup is also opening. Is there any way to prevent that...?

Comment: Just don't do anything on click, you will get redirected by the href. I just put an alert for demonstration purposes (Remove -> alert('clicked!!');).

Comment: I have already removed those alerts. Click function is working now. But after that time period its opening that popup..

Comment: $(document).on('mouseenter', '#link', function() {  setTimeout(function() {  var that = $(this);
    if (!that.hasClass('clicked')) {  method2();
    }
  }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('click', '#link', function() {  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('clicked');
  method1();
});

Answer (score 0):

If opening another page on click is all you want to do, why not just put a link in the href attribute?
Like this: `<a href='http://example.com' onmouseover='method2()'>SOMETHING</a>`

Comment: You're right, but this is not an answer to the question. You should have posted it as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response Labbed. But thats not what i want.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought the problem was that the onclick event didn't fire or something.
I also thought that the "popup" was a popup menu below the link, that would not obscure it.
In my opinion, having a popup open on hovering a link seems like bad design in general, but I don't know what you are trying to do.