# How to create both onClick and mouseover to a link jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, hover, mouseover

I have this script to change main image on click to a link with .feature_thumb class. I want to make it so that it's both click and hover.

```
$(".feature_thumb").click(function(){

   var main_href = $(this).attr('href');

   change_image(main_href );

});
```

Can someone help me with this?

I tried this but it didn't work...

```
$(".feature_thumb").on('click hover') function(){

   var main_href = $(this).attr('href');

   change_image(main_href );

});
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine hover and click functions (jQuery)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432003/combine-hover-and-click-functions-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hover()` jQuery method is a shorthand for `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`
In fact you want `mouseover`:

```
$(".feature_thumb").on('click mouseover', function(){...});
```

Or depending exact expected behaviour and HTML markup, use `mouseenter`.

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax is slightly off but it looks fine otherwise and should work.

Notice that in your code sample there are more closing parentheses than opening ones.

```
$(".feature_thumb").on('click hover', function(){

   var main_href = $(this).attr('href');

   change_image(main_href );

});
```

Also as other people have pointed out the hover event is actually two events. Hover is shorthand for `$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );`

Comment: There is no event `hover`

Comment: Jquery includes a 'hover' event that allows one or two methods to be bound for when the mouse enters and exits the element https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This is a shorthand method, but `on()` is to bind event: http://jsfiddle.net/xy1hoco0/