# Jquery display clicked image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display the current rating image for example 3 stars along with its rating definition when the user clicks the desired rating and have it stay on that rating until the user picks a different rating.

Or have the rating jump back to the rating the user has currently picked when the user hovers over other rating values with out choosing (clicking) a different rating.

So far I can only display the rating images and definitions when the user hovers over them, but not when the user clicks on them.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul class="rating notrated">
        <li id="rate-1" data-desc="Bad">
            <label for="rating-1"><input type="radio" value="1" name="rating" id="rating-1" />1 star</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-2" data-desc="Good">
            <label for="rating-2"><input type="radio" value="2" name="rating" id="rating-2" />2 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-3" data-desc="Great">
            <label for="rating-3"><input type="radio" value="3" name="rating" id="rating-3" />3 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-4" data-desc="Better">
            <label for="rating-4"><input type="radio" value="4" name="rating" id="rating-4" />4 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-5" data-desc="Best">
            <label for="rating-5"><input type="radio" value="5" name="rating" id="rating-5" />5 stars</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rate">Rate this product</div>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rating li')
    .on('mouseenter touchstart', function() {
            var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
            $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
            $('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
    })
    .on('mouseleave touchend', function() {
            var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().removeClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
            $('.rate').text('Rate this product');
    }); 
});
```

CSS

```
.rating{
    height: 30px;
}

.notrated{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.rating-1{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -30px;
}

.rating-2{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -60px;
}

.rating-3{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -90px;
}

.rating-4{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -120px;
}

.rating-5{
    background-image: url('./stars.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -150px;
}
```

Comment: add `click` event along with `mouseenter touchstart`

Comment: that did not seem to work.

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432003/combine-hover-and-click-functions-jquery

Comment: Add `mousedown` instead of `click`

Comment: `$('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));` might better be `$('.rate').text($(this).data('desc'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little modification to you code and added a click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating li')
    .on('mouseenter touchstart', function() {
      var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
      $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
      $('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
    })
    .on('mouseleave touchend', function() {
      var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().removeClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
      $('.rate').text($('.rate').attr('data-desc'));
    })
    .on('click', function() {
      $('.rate').attr('data-desc', $(this).attr('data-desc'))
    });
});
```

I also added the initial description to `data-desc` attriubute of `.rate` element

```
<div data-desc="Rate this product" class="rate">Rate this product</div>
```

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8es85nzr/1/)

Comment: This works for keeping the rating description but I can't seem to keep the rating image.

Comment: Why not `$('.rate').data('desc', $(this).data('desc'));` instead of `$('.rate').attr('data-desc', $(this).attr('data-desc'))`

Comment: I found out how to get the rating image to stay but I cant change it after I will have to ask another question if I cant figure it out thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `change` event separately for `checkbox` to maintain the "RATED" text after the mouse leave.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var checked = false, checkedElem;
        $('.rating li')
        .on('mouseenter touchstart', function () {
            var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
            $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
            $('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
        })
        .on('mouseleave touchend', function () {
            var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
            if (checked) {
                var classSuffix1 = checkedElem.attr('id').split('-')[1];
                $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix1);
                $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
                $('.rate').text(checkedElem.closest('li').attr('data-desc'));
            }
            else {
                $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().removeClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
                $('.rate').text('Rate this product');
            }
        });
        $('.rating li input')
        .on('change', function () {
            checkedElem = $(this);
            var classSuffix = checkedElem.attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
            $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
            $('.rate').text(checkedElem.closest('li').attr('data-desc'));
            checked = true;                
        })
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c562h8nL/)

Comment: @linkNES Please check the fiddle example and tell me what does not work.

Comment: I cant seem to get the rating image for the selected rating to stay.

Comment: I found out how to get the rating image to stay but I cant change it after I will have to ask another question if I cant figure it out thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

This should: vary the rating until one is clicked (with mouse over).
When one IS clicked (selected) then it keeps that rating until it is changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating li').on('mouseenter touchstart', function() {
      var checked = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
      var hasCheck = checked.length;
      var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
      $('.rating').nextAll().removeClass('notrated');
      if (hasCheck) {
        $('.rate').text(checked.parents('li').data('desc'));
      } else {
        $('.rate').text($(this).data('desc'));
      }
    })
    .on('mouseleave touchend', function() {
      var hasCheck = $('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
      var classSuffix = $(this).find('input').attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('.rating').prevAll().addBack().removeClass('rating-' + classSuffix);
      if (!hasCheck) {
        $('.rate').text('Rate this product');
      }
    })
    .on('change click', 'input[type=radio]', function() {
      var checked = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
      var hasCheck = checked.length;
      if (hasCheck) {
        $('.rate').text(checked.parents('li').data('desc'));
      } else {
        $('.rate').text('Rate this product');
      }
    });
});
```

NOTE: this also takes care of issues if it gets changed with code: i.e.

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", false);
$('input[type=radio]').trigger('change');
```

Play around with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/Lczv8zzj/

Comment: I cant seem to get the rating image for the selected rating to stay.

Comment: Modify the images code to match the "text" code - I have no images so that is more difficult to test in a fiddle etc. i.e. move it inside the if statements to match (and in the change handler)

Comment: I found out how to get the rating image to stay but I cant change it after I will have to ask another question if I cant figure it out thanks for all the help.